# Queuing work items to the thread pool using System.Threading.Task

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool, portable-class-library

I'd like to know which (if any) is the most straightforward way of queuing work items (delegates) to the thread pool in .Net 4.5 using `System.Threading.Task` objects. What I want to do essentially is to replicate the queuing functionality of the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` method with `Task`s. Please correct me if i'm wrong, but as far as I know the work items enqueued using this method are guaranteed to be executed in the order they were enqueued (maybe I'm completely wrong for multi-processor scenarios). I have to write code that behaves the same, using `Task`s.

I am working on a portable class library, so that's why I can't use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`, but instead I have to rely on `Task`s for this objective. What technique would you suggest? Is the default task scheduler suitable for this requirement?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the PCL picks the proper TaskScheduler for each platform itself. Check the edit on my answer, but I'll have to test this some more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask is exactly what Tasks do already. A Task is essentially a wrapper around a lambda that by default gets queued to execute on the ThreadPool. On top of that, Tasks add continuations, exception handling, cancellation and many convenience functions that make multi-threading a lot easier.

If you don't want to use the ThreadPool, you can create your own [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) and use it when creating a new Task.  A TaskScheduler essentially receives a Task and schedules it for execution.

The default TaskScheduler uses ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem plus some work-stealing magic and multiple queue handling. Other implementations can use a priority queue, set their own limits on the maximum or minimum number of threads or whatever technique their author wants to use.

**EDIT**

I didn't notice the  **Portable** part from the beginning. So the question is "Does the PCL provide a TaskScheduler that uses the ThreadPool or do I have to create my own"?

<s>.NET 4+ provides the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler. Unfortunately, this seems to be missing from the PCL subset. It looks that you may have to create your own TaskScheduler or use a Nuget Package to add platform specific implementations.</s>

Somehow, I think that ThreadPoolTaskScheduler would be a bad choice for a Windows Phone project

After some diggind using Resharper and .NET's debug symbols, I think the PCL finds any available platform TaskScheduler implementations by itself.

In .NET 4.0, TaskScheduler.Default returns an instance of ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, an interal BCL class. In the PCL subset, TaskScheduler.Default returns null and ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is not available.

The source code for ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is probalby available from  Microsoft's Reference Source Servers, but you can also browse it quickly at [dotnetframework.org](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler@cs/1305376/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler@cs)

I created a PCL class that returns a new task and called it from a .NET 4.5 console application to see what TaskScheduler it would use. I found that the PCL class actually used the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

I haven't tried this with a Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 project yet, although I suspect I'll get each platform's default TaskScheduler.

Comment: Indeed, I eventually reached the same conclusion, that a custom `TaskScheduler` is the way to go, the only problem being that it's a bit of a pain to implement one in a portable class library project, due to lack of `ThreadPool`. I could only do it through dependency injection from platform-specific libraries referencing the portable class library.

Comment: @GabrielS., I'm confused.  What is wrong with `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`?  It is listed as being supported for a portable class library.

Comment: It's about the schedulers, not the Tasks themselves. The abstract class TaskScheduler is available yet it returns `null` as the current and default instances. The concrete ThreadPoolTaskScheduler class, which is the default for most platforms, is missing from the portable libraries

Comment: Except the “work-stealing magic and multiple queue handling” mean that `Task`s **won't** execute in the order they were scheduled in.

Comment: @svick What about a custom implementation of `TaskScheduler` with `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` set to 1 - like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) -, shouldn't this mean it acts as a serial, FIFO queue?

Comment: @GabrielS. That depends entirely on the implementation of that `TaskScheduler`. It would most likely mean that, but that's because a custom scheduler is most likely going to be simple, not because of concurrency level. And with the scheduler you linked to, you can't change `MaximumConcurrencyLevel`.

Comment: There is no `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, at least not as a public type in .Net itself.

Comment: There is, it just isn't public. Use Reflector or Resharper to see what goes on under the abstract TaskScheduler, eg `private static readonly TaskScheduler s_defaultTaskScheduler = (TaskScheduler) new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();`

Answer (score 4):

`ThreadPool` is not required to execute delegates in exactly the same order as they were scheduled (at least I didn't find any guarantees like that in the documentation). But as far as I know, it is pretty much how it behaves.

`Task`s (with the default `TaskScheduler`) are more complicated, because they use thread-local queues, that are processed in LIFO order. If you want to make sure all your `Task`s go to the global FIFO queue, you can use [`TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/07/07/9822857.aspx). But again, it's not documented what exactly does that do, so the specifics can change.

Comment: Notice the question is about the *Portable* libraries, where you may not even have any implementations of TaskScheduler to use. Gabriel is essentially asking "Is there a TaskScheduler that uses the ThreadPool in the PCL or do I have to roll my own for each target platform"?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not how I understand the question. It doesn't ask for `ThreadPool`, it asks for a way to schedule `Task`s in a FIFO way. And `PreferFairness` (which seems to be available in PCLs) does exactly that.

Comment: @svick That's actually right, i only mentioned `ThreadPool` as a (probably not so good) example, FIFO scheduling of `Task`s is what i was looking for. I'll try to see if the `PreferFairness` option is indeed a solution for the default schedulers on the multiple platforms targeted by my portable class library.

Comment: @svick Unfortunately, `PreferFairness` - as its name suggests - does not ensure FIFO ordering, at least not on Windows Phone 8, i just tried it. After all, a custom task scheduler seems the most reliable solution.